# export scrapy to csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am going to scrape 'healthunblock.com'; I don't know why I cannot see the extracted data in the CSV file.

```py
class HealthSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'health'
    #allowed_domains = ['https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts#popular']
    start_urls = ['https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts#popular']
    itemlist=[]

    def parse(self, response):
        
        all_div_posts = response.xpath('//div[@class="results-posts"]')
        
        for posts in all_div_posts:
            items={} 
            items['title']= posts.xpath('//h3[@class="results-post__title"]/text()').extract()
            items['post']= posts.xpath('//div[@class="results-post__body hidden-xs"]/text()').extract()
            self.itemlist.append(items)
          
           
        with open("outputfile.csv","w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f,['title','post'])
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in self.itemlist:
                writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: you can run `scrapy ... -o outputfile.csv` and it will save result in csv file - you don't have to write code for this - you have to only `yield` every row of data. But if you relly want to do this then your problem can be "w" (write mode) which remove previous content when you run it again - and parse is executed many times so it may remove previous content many times.

Comment: you can always use `print()` to see values in variable - maybe it never get any data so it can save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I run your code and it gives me file with results.

---

Scrapy can built-it function to save result in `CSV` and you don't have to write on your own.

You have to only `yield` items

```
def parse(self, response):
    
    all_div_posts = response.xpath('//div[@class="results-posts"]')
    
    for posts in all_div_posts:
        items = {} 
        items['title']= posts.xpath('//h3[@class="results-post__title"]/text()').extract()
        items['post']= posts.xpath('//div[@class="results-post__body hidden-xs"]/text()').extract()

        yield items
```

and run with option `-o outputfile.csv`

```
scrapy runspider your_spider.py -o outputfile.csv
```

---

**EDIT:**

I made some changes and now both version gives the same result - I checked it using program `diff` to compare both `csv`.

Because I organized items in different way so I could use directly `writer.writerows(self.itemlist)` without `for`-loop (and `zip()`)

I also use `.get()` instead of `extract()` (or `extract_first()`) to get single title and single post to create pair. And I can use `strip()` to clear spaces.

**Version 1**

```
import scrapy
import csv

class HealthSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'health'
    #allowed_domains = ['https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts#popular']
    start_urls = ['https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts#popular']
    
    itemlist = []

    def parse(self, response):
        
        all_div_posts = response.xpath('//div[@class="results-post"]')
        print('len(all_div_posts):', len(all_div_posts))
        
        for one_post in all_div_posts:
            #print('>>>>>>>>>>>>')
            one_item = {
                'title': one_post.xpath('.//h3[@class="results-post__title"]/text()').get().strip(),
                'post': one_post.xpath('.//div[@class="results-post__body hidden-xs"]/text()').get().strip(),
            }
            self.itemlist.append(one_item)

            #yield one_item
          
                   
        with open("outputfile.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ['title','post'])
            writer.writeheader()           
            writer.writerows(self.itemlist)
```

**Version 2**

```
import scrapy

class HealthSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'health'
    #allowed_domains = ['https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts#popular']
    start_urls = ['https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts#popular']
    
    #itemlist = []

    def parse(self, response):
        
        all_div_posts = response.xpath('//div[@class="results-post"]')
        print('len(all_div_posts):', len(all_div_posts))
        
        for one_post in all_div_posts:
            #print('>>>>>>>>>>>>')
            one_item = {
                'title': one_post.xpath('.//h3[@class="results-post__title"]/text()').get().strip(),
                'post': one_post.xpath('.//div[@class="results-post__body hidden-xs"]/text()').get().strip(),
            }
            #self.itemlist.append(one_item)

            yield one_item
          
                   
        #with open("outputfile.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
        #    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ['title','post'])
        #    writer.writeheader()           
        #    writer.writerows(self.itemlist)
```

Comment: many thanks, I am going to save the data for each post in a row. This command doesn't work for my concern.

Comment: @TaherehMaghsoudi but this code saves every post in separated row. Maybe you open CSV in wrong way.

Comment: sorry I am a bit confused what is your mean by opening CSV in a wrong way? I run the following command:  scrapy crawl health -o output.csv

Comment: I compared result from your code and from my code na strange is that my version  (with `-o output.csv`) gives me data in separated rows but your version (with `csv.DictWriter`) save all in one row - it converts list with all post to one string.

Comment: I removed the codes related to export to CSV from my program (csv.DictWriter) and then I try to export the data by that command that you mentioned, but all data saved in the same row.

Comment: I think I found problem - you use `@class="results-posts"` with `s` at the end which gives single `<div>` with all posts as single element - see `len(all_div_posts)` - but you should use `@class="results-posts"` without `s` which gives list with 30 posts.

Comment: Many thanks, I followed what you mentioned but then I had a CSV file including 30 recording data, and each row has that same data. Indeed, all data for all posts were exported to a row and repeated 30 times.

Comment: I think you try to get it in different way as I would do so finally you want to save it in different way as I would do (and as scrapy does it). You get one div with all posts and later you get list with all `titles` and list with all `posts` - and it would need `zip()` to create pairs `one title, one post` and save it in separated rows.

Comment: I try to get every post as separated item and in every post search single `title` and single `post` and directly create pair `one title, one post` - this way when there will be no title or post then I can pust some default value. But I had problem with `extract()` which always gives list - even if there is only one title or one post  - and this was making some problem with my version. I needed `extract_first()` or `extract[0]` OR new fucntion `get()` which will replace `extract_first()`

Comment: I added both versions with all changes.

Comment: I used both versions but they return just 4 items. and what they record is different from what I can see on the website.

Comment: I don't remeber this page - it was almost month ago - but they could add new elements on server - ie. they could add `JavaScript` which adds elements on page but `scrapy` can't run `JavaScript`, and they could add code which send different HTML for different devices (notebook, tablet, phone) and `scrapy` may get different `HTML` then your browser. I would have to create again minimal working code to run it and see problem.

Comment: I tested both versions and they give me 30 items - the same items which I see in web browser. But browser normally shows 36 - but when I turn off JavaScript then browser also shows 30 items.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get the exact results that you see in that webpage. The content are dynamic and you need to populate the json content in order to fetch the required results. I've used customized approach to write the data in a csv file. If you go for the way below, the csv file will be opened once. However, the file will be closed after the data are written to it.

```
import csv
import json
import scrapy

class HealthSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "health"
    start_urls = ['https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/popular']

    def __init__(self):
        self.outfile = open("output.csv","w",newline="",encoding="utf-8-sig")
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.outfile)
        self.writer.writerow(['title','post content'])

    def close(self,reason):
        self.outfile.close()

    def parse(self,response):
        for posts in json.loads(response.body_as_unicode()):
            title = ' '.join(posts['title'].split())
            post = ' '.join(posts['bodySnippet'].split())
            self.writer.writerow([title,post])
            yield {'title':title,'post':post}
```